# Masking LiDAR points to create DEM in ArcGIS Pro with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, lidar, masking

I have an irregular LiDAR point cloud dataset, so when I try to create a DEM or DSM, the points are connected across the irregular edges of the LiDAR point cloud.

I thought that creating a mask would help, but this doesn't seem to work. Here is my example code:

```
lasd = "mylasd.lasd"
arcpy.env.mask = "myMask" ## this is boundary of LiDAR point cloud
outname = "dem"
dem_layer = arcpy.CreateUniqueName('dem_layer')
arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(lasd, dem_layer,class_code=classCodes,
                                     return_values=return_Vals)
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster(dem_layer, outname, "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 10, 1)
arcpy.Delete_management(dem_layer)
```

Using the mask doesn't result in any difference. Is the correct way to create the DEM and then, crop it? This seems more time-intensive, so I want to avoid this step if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The environment property `mask` from the `env` class is neither supported in [Make LAS Dataset Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-las-dataset-layer.htm) nor is it in [Las Dataset To Raster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm) (see their corresponding 'Environments' section).

On the other hand, an alternative is to use [Extract by Mask](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm) to clip the output DEM from `Las Dataset To Raster` tool. For example:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import * #Extract by Mask tool

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/data'
arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management("mylasd.lasd", "ground_lasd", class_code=[2]) # Make LAS Dataset Layer is necessary if the point cloud needs filtering. Here points are filtered per class code 2 (ground points).
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster("ground_lasd", "dem.tif", "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 10, 1)

outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask("dem", "myMask.shp") #myMask.shp is the vector boundary of LiDAR point cloud
outExtractByMask.save("clipped_dem")
```

Additionally, `ExtractByMask` supports the environment setting `arcpy.env.mask`, if one wants to use it:

```
arcpy.env.mask = "myMask.shp"
outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask("dem")
outExtractByMask.save("clipped_dem")
```