# ArcPy IDW interpolation with LiDAR point cloud data

Tags: arcpy, interpolation, lidar, point-cloud, error-000622

There are several questions such as [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285279/masking-lidar-points-to-create-dem-in-arcgis-pro-with-arcpy), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318607/creating-idw-rasters-from-each-field-in-large-point-feature-set-using-arcpy-for) etc on interpolation, but, when I implement the same procedure to calculate digital terrain model from point cloud I get an error:

```
las_path = r"C:\Users\testdata"

# Create a LAS dataset object
las_dataset = arcpy.management.CreateLasDataset(las_path, "las_dataset")

# Create the LAS dataset layer

ground_returns = arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(las_dataset, "LASD_Layer",class_code=[2])

# Set the extent for the DTM
extent = arcpy.Describe(ground_returns).extent

# Set the cell size and output raster path
output_raster = r"C:\Users\test\testdata\dtmLayer.tif"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# idw
arcpy.Idw(ground_returns, "ELEVATION" output_raster, cell_size = 5, power=2, search_radius=None, output_prediction_error = True)

Then comes the error   

    # change to another interpolation method
arcpy.Kriging_3d(ground_returns, "ELEVATION", output_raster, "Spherical", 1, 2) # using "Z" gives similar error

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000860: Input point features: is not the type of Composite Geodataset, or does not exist.
WARNING 001000: Z value field: Field ELEVATION does not exist
Failed to execute (Kriging).
```

Borrow another line copied from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284841/selecting-lidar-return-point-type-in-lidar-dataset-with-arcpy) with modification of interpolation method, error:

```
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster("LASD_Layer", "ground_returns", "ELEVATION", "IDW", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 5, 2)

ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (LAS Dataset To Raster). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter interpolation_type.

# only "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR" seems to work, everything else fails
```

Comment: Interesting,  The error suggests that "IDW" is not a good parameter.  What happens if you change that to one of the other Interpolation Type options?  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm

Comment: You need to read the help file on the LasDatasetToRaster tool! Look at the usage section and then the code samples on the _interpolation_type_ parameter, you have entered nothing more than the text IDW yet in the sample code it is a spaced separated set of parameters. That is the source of your error.

Comment: Changing to <BINNING IDW LINEAR> worked. Seems I just jumped right in without reading documentation. Thanks for pointing that out.